# Importing other components, "exactly one root element."

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Sorry for the neophyte question. I'm trying to render a .vue file with children and a parent, and I'm getting a "more than one root element" error. What strikes me as odd, is that the components that are being imported are *supposed* to be wrapped in a `<div>` -- I don't understand, therefore, how there could be more than one root element.

This was working when I was importing `ServerList.vue` and `ServerDetails.vue` separately into my `App.vue` (main) file.

Code (`ServerReadouts.vue`):

```
<template>
    </div class="row">
        <server-list></server-list>
        <server-details></server-details>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ServerList from './ServerList.vue'
import ServerDetails from './ServerDetails.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        'server-list': ServerList,
        'server-details': ServerDetails
    }

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Code (`App.vue`):

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <app-header></app-header>
        <app-server-readouts></app-server-readouts>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './Header.vue'
import Footer from './Footer.vue'
import ServerReadouts from './ServerReadouts.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            'app-header': Header,
            'app-footer': Footer,
            'app-server-readouts': ServerReadouts,
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Console error:

```
./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler.js?id=data-v-7ea00901!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/ServerReadouts.vue
template syntax error Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.
 @ ./src/ServerReadouts.vue 11:23-154
 @ ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is because a typo in your `ServerReadouts.vue` HTML structure. So you just define it like this:

```html
<template>
    </div class="row">
        <server-list></server-list>
        <server-details></server-details>
    </div>
</template>
```

Which, there is no opening `div` at all here, so since **each component should have a single root, in your case it will consider it as four different elements as roots**. Which are two `div`s, `server-list`, and `server-details`. So the final render result will be something like this:

```html
<template>
    <div></div>
    <server-list></server-list>
    <server-details></server-details>
    <div></div>
</template>
```

Which is not correct at all.

So to fix it, you can do this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <server-list></server-list>
        <server-details></server-details>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Yep... I just found that. Thank you.